# Haskell logical output error

Tags: haskell

Here is my following code which is meant to filter out the films that contains the users names below is my database

```
 testDatabase :: [Film]
testDatabase = [
                    ("Casino Royale", ["Daniel Craig", "Eva Green", "Judi Dench"], 2006, ["Garry", "Dave", "Zoe", "Kevin", "Emma"]),
                ("The Departed", ["Leonardo DiCaprio", "Matt Damon", "Jack Nicholson"], 2006, ["Zoe", "Emma", "Paula", "Olga", "Dave"]),
                ("Inception", ["Leonardo DiCaprio"], 2010, ["Chris", "Emma", "Jo", "Bill", "Dave", "Liz", "Wally", "Zoe", "Amy", "Sam", "Paula", "Kevin", "Olga"]),
                ("Up in the Air", ["George Clooney", "Vera Farmiga"], 2009, ["Wally", "Liz", "Kevin", "Tim", "Emma"]),
                ("The Shawshank Redemption", ["Tim Robbins", "Morgan Freeman"], 1994, ["Jo", "Wally", "Liz", "Tim", "Sam", "Zoe", "Emma", "Garry", "Olga", "Kevin"])
           ]
```

And here is there function which does as specifed above

```
showFanFilms :: String -> [Film] -> [Film]
showFanFilms name database
 =  filter(\(title, cast, year, fan:fans) -> fan == name) database
```

every time I run the code with the correct input for example

```
showFanFilms "Tim" testDatabase
```

it keeps giving me an empty array

```
   []
```

Any ideas why?

Comment: type Title = String
       type Actor = String
        type Cast = [Actor]
         type Year = Int
          type Fan = String
    type Fans = [Fan]

    type Film = (Title, Cast, Year, Fans)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the pattern `fan:fans`, `fan` becomes bound to only the *first* element in a list of fans. Since `"Tim"` never occurs at that spot, you get no hits.

You probably want something like

```
showFanFilms name database
 =  filter(\(title, cast, year, fans) -> name `elem` fans) database
```

instead.

Comment: Ahhh GREAT. its working now thanks! Am i correct by assuming that elem is a function which searches through a specific string in a list?

Comment: Yes, although it works for lists of other types than strings as well.